# JAX-WS - how to create an element of type xs:any from server side code?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, xsd, jax-ws

I have created an XML schema for my webservice, and the element for ServerResponse contains an unbounded sequence of elements of type xs:any.

I am generating classes (using xjc) from my schema, and so this sequence is converted to List in the generated ServerResponse class.

The ServerResponse class has a method, getAny(), which returns this List and allows me to make changes to it.. but I can't figure out exactly how to do this.

Say I want to add a couple of elements to the sequence of any objects in the response, so that the XML of the response will contain this.

```
<someelement1>sometext</someelement1>
<someelement2>somemoretext</someelement2>
```

from the Java server side code, how would I add these two elements to the getAny() object?
I thought it could be done something like this:

```
Object element = new Object();
((Element)element).setNodeValue("someelement1");
((Element)element).setTextContent("sometext");
requestobject.getAny().add(element);
```

However this doesn't work, as it throws an error stating that "java.lang.object cannot be cast to org.w3.dom.Element".

Can anyone help me do this? I'm sure there's a pretty simple solution!

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Note: I meant List<Object> for the type of the generated getAny() method!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Object`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) does not implement [`Element`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html), so this cast will always fail.

You can create `Element` instances using a [`DocumentBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html) which you can get from a [`DocumentBuilderFactory`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html).

Here is some sample JAXB code:

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Anything {
  private Object any;

  @XmlAnyElement
  public Object getAny() { return any; }
  public void setAny(Object any) { this.any = any; }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws DOMException,
      ParserConfigurationException {
    Element foo = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
        .newDocumentBuilder()
        .newDocument()
        .createElement("foo");
    Anything a = new Anything();
    a.setAny(foo);
    JAXB.marshal(a, System.out);
  }
}
```

*I haven't tried this under JAX-WS (JAX-WS uses JAXB bindings) - if it doesn't work, I'd start digging round the [javax.xml.soap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/soap/package-summary.html) package.*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I can't try it until monday but I will try it then and let you know if it works!

Comment: Hi McDowell, I have tried your suggestion but unfortunately not had any luck. The XML printed by the JAXB.marshal call in System.out looked correct <someelement>text</someelement> but I got the following error in the response message: <faultstring>Marshalling Error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'someelement'. One of '{WC[##other:"http://somenamespace"]}' is expected.</faultstring> .. I spent a couple of hours playing around with it, and also tried using a JAXBElement<String>  instead but got a very similar error with

Comment: that too... Do you have any other ideas? Thanks again

Comment: Oh, and also in the printed output from the JAXB.marshal call, there was an xml declaration.. something like <xml? 1.0 ... />  which came before the <someelement>text</someelement> XML. I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem, but thought I'd mention it in case!

Comment: (one other thing to mention: I have also tried setting the processContent="skip" property of the xs:any element. But got the same error as above with that too)

Comment: @Jimmy - I'd say the service is expecting the unstructured elements to be namespaced - try using `document.createElementNS` - [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createElementNS%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: processContent="skip" worked for me for JAX-WS service which returns <xs:any/> in one of the fields.